# Is Faraday's Law universally applicable?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, classical-electrodynamics

> I would say it is **NOT** a duplicate of this question: [Faraday's paradox](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146628/faradays-paradox) .

While I was studying Faraday's law of classical electromagnetism, I came across this picture:
[image: Faraday's disk]

It is called Faraday's disk and it works as a DC dynamo on a constant magnetic field. However, when I tried to apply Faraday's law I failed:
$$
\epsilon = - \frac{d\phi_B}{dt}
$$
If both the area of the circuit and the magnetic field are constant (even their direction), I would expect the flux to be also constant. Furthermore, knowing the flux is constant its derivative to time must be zero, so there shouldn't be any inducted electromotive force. **It turns out there is.**

This is called the Faraday Paradox and it even has its own [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_paradox) article and it is also mentioned here: [Faraday's law of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction).

Moreover, the second article (which gives a mathematical proof of the Law from Maxwell Equations) claims that Faraday's Law is not universally applicable and also that Faraday's Disk is a nice counterexample. Is this statement true?

- If so, when can this Law be applied and why (mathematical explanations are also welcome)?
- If it is an universal law, how can this case be explained?

Comment: How is this not [a duplicate of the question you link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146628/)?  I can't see any substantive difference.

Comment: My idea was to use Faraday's disk (see picture above) to show a controversial situation. However, my main goal is not to understand how it works, but to know why some people (and Wikipedia) claim that Faraday's law cannot be applied there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faraday's paradox](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146628/)

Comment: I feel it's a duplicate, and flagged the same.